# Can I use another GPIO pin on the Pi 3 as a RX UART?

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial

I accidently plugged 5v in to the RX UART pin 15 on my Pi, now I'm unable to receive communication on this pin from my connected device. I was wondering if it's possible to use a different GPIO pin as an RX pin to receive serial ?

Answer (score 1):

This question may sound simple.  However it is likely dependent on if the processor's hardware UART resource is mappable to different (functional) pins as well as if the Linux UART driver is flexible enough to be configurable for this alteration to the UART feature of the Raspberry Pi.  Even if both of these features are available, such a change likely involves recompiling the driver if not the kernel.  This usually involves having an installed compiler and installed kernel source code (you need the kernel source code even if you are only compiling the driver).  Not a light subject.

On the other hand, people do write code to simulate a UART on other Raspberry Pi pins.  This is usually done when the actual hardware UART is committed to another activity.  In such a case, this [Raspberry Pi stackexchange answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27488/pigpio-library-example-for-bit-banging-a-uart) provides a good example.

If you have further Raspberry Pi questions, you may have better luck if you ask them on the [Raspberry Pi stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) web site.